# Why "set lines=999 " can't maximize Gvim winodw when opening?

Tags: vim

`set lines=999` in vimrc can't maximize Gvim winodw when opening, why? Please check the screenshot, there's some space in the right and bottom side.

[image]

Comment: I don't see your screen shot. However, in my case `set lines=999` sets my gvim window to the biggest number of lines that can fit on my screen: not to the full height of my screen, but the unused vertical space isn't large enough to fit another line. I tested this on a Windows machine, it works interactively and in my `.gvimrc`. Maybe you should specify your full environment - OS, window manager, etc - someone with a similar configuration is more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

As Joanis stated in his comment, Vim works with lines of character that have a fixed height. The window can only be resized in steps of line-height and character-width.

If you change your font size (Edit -> Select font...) you will see, that the gap between the Vim window and the monitor border changes.

If you are lucky, you'll find a font/font-size that exactly matches the maximum resolution of your monitor. Whether that is still useful or readable ... most likely not.

Comment: I have add a screenshot.

Comment: @Joeyyy That doesn't change my statement. Also note that there is a difference between telling Vim to display as much lines/columns as possible and telling the OS/Window-Manager to maximize a window.